# using rendered page links via java client

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am given a url , I need to get this url html and from there get this site links . 
I thought about using headless browsers . I m using java so I would like to sum it up using java process.
an example can be cnn site ... 
So far I have tried using :

> testCompile 'net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.32'

```
   @Test
     public void htmlUnitTest() throws Exception {

      try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {

        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(20000);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(URL);
        WebResponse response = page.getWebResponse();
        String content = response.getContentAsString();

        List<HtmlAnchor> anchors = page.getAnchors();

        System.out.println("anchors.size() : " + anchors.size());
        System.out.println("***********");
        System.out.println(content);
        System.out.println("***********");

        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("htmlUnit.txt"))) {
            writer.write(content);
        }
    }
}
```

but the response I am getting the original HTML without being rendered (the java script havent worked and created the page anchors in my case )

can someone recommend on another library , or tell me if I miss using html unit and can suggest a working solution it will be very helpful.

Comment: please provide the url to give us a chance to reproduce your case

Comment: any site which has rendering try for instance https://edition.cnn.com

Answer (score 0):

The waitForBackgroundJavaScriptXX methods are not options; you have to call them AFTER getPage(URL) or any other interaction like click().

One of the major differences between HtmlUnit and Selenium is the integration of all parts. In HtmlUnit the javascript engine is part or the implementation, this implies that the api is able to get information about the current status. As a result waitForBackgroundJavaScriptXX methods are only waiting, if there is some javascript pending. If there is none they are no ops.

Comment: this js is the page being render once the java script is being interpreted on page start . without any event triggering ...
and the motivation is to be website agnostic , meaning  I don't want to be aware to this site architecture ...
how real world crawlers such yahoo and google does it ?